# Upload file using vuejs and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I want to upload pdf file using vuejs and laravel but I got an error:

> Call to a member function store() on array.

**my vue component:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input v-model="form." type="text" name="" placeholder="" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('') }">
  <has-error :form="form" field="title"></has-error>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" name="" placeholder="" @change="addFile" class="form-input" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('file') }">
</div>

...

data(){
  return{
    form: new Form({
      title:'',
      file:''
    }),  
},
methods:{
  addFile(e){
    this.form.file=e.target.files[0];
  },
  createFile(){
    this.form.post('/api/profpub')
  }
},
```

**My controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $pub = Profpub::create([
    'titre'=>$request['titre'],
    'file'=>$request->file->store(),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: What is `Profpub` exactly ?

Comment: The controller .